# How to copy large files into Docker image without saving in history

Tags: docker

I have a large folder (2GB) that contains source code that I will compile inside of a Docker image. The compiled programs are significantly smaller (roughly 120MB) and since I want to keep my image small, I'm trying to prevent plainly running the `COPY` command since it would create a new layer. However, there doesn't seem to really be a way to have a `COPY` + `RUN` command at the same time.

Is there a way to `COPY` something into a Docker image and later remove it from the history or prevent it from creating a layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's unfortunately not included in the Dockerfile syntax (I'd love the feature myself). There are two workarounds:

1. Host the file somewhere and pull it with a wget command as one part of your `RUN` line. It's ugly and not portable to others building your image.
2. Use the currently experimental `docker build --squash` option that was [just released in 1.13.0](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/22641). You'll need to update the dockerd to startup with experimental options enabled.

Comment: Sad there's no real way around it besides squashing it... It means that I need multiple Dockerfiles so that if I need to change something, I don't have to run every `RUN` step every time (since they can take 10-20 minutes each).

Comment: With caching, you can avoid running every RUN step if you put your frequently changing lines at the end of the Dockerfile. But if you squash it, I believe you're right that you lose that benefit.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running docker 17.05 or later, you can also use [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/). Roughly, your Dockerfile could look something like:

```
FROM build-dependencies as build
COPY src src
RUN src/build.sh

FROM run-dependencies
COPY --from=build src/build .
```